# Installing msi with c# not working properly

Tags: c#, process, installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to install 3 msi drivers one after another.
There are all in the same folder and I'm using the same attrubutes for all of them/

I already did it before and it worked fine, but now I don't know what possibly can go wrong.

```
string attributesToDownload = "REINSTALL=ALL /qb- /norestart";
Process proc = Process.Start("msiexec.exe", string.Format("/i \"{0}\" {1}", driverPath, attributesToDownload));
proc.WaitForExit();
return proc.ExitCode;
```

The curious thing is:
For the first driver my ExitCode is 1603.
For the second sriver the ExitCode is 0 but the driver is not really installed.
For the third one it all works fine.

When I tried to install the first and the second drivers directly from cmd with the same attributes it installed succesfully.
"msiexec /i driverPath REINSTALL=ALL /qb- /norestart"

Waiting for some ideas.....

Comment: If you are the one who created these installations, start by logging them (`/l*v path\to\verbose.log`). If you did not create these installations, this question is likely a better fit for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I think.... without the REINSTALL=ALL, the only way to do it (that I found) is uninstalling the current version and than installing the new one

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing REINSTALL=ALL to get this to work, then you are updating an existing product installed on the system. That's ok, maybe you want to patch the existing product, but you don't seem to be aware that you cannot install the same product twice - the newer one needs to a patch or and update like your REINSTALL=ALL or a major upgrade. If you want to uninstall the older one then you need a major upgrade!!! There is no need to uninstall the older version because a major upgrade does that automatically.